# I want to remove input method completly

Tags: windows-8.1

I use English(US) and Arabic Egypt as input method but there is Arabic Saudi   Arabia added Automatically i can not remove it when i go to language preferences I did not find it
also in options there's only one language English us & Arabic Egypt
Please tell me how could i remove the Arabic Saudi Arabia from language?

Comment: I am battling with this exact same problem. You can fix it temporarily by adding the entries in language preferences and then deleting them again. Unfortunately it will pop up again after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help: On Win7, I go to Control Panel>Region and Language>Keyboards and Languages.